# React Native Contacts: NonNull error in ContactsProvider?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want read contacts in Android with react-native-contacts. I run these two commands `npm install react-native-contacts --save` and `react-native link`.
And also added
 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS " />`

after that I checked settings.gradle, build.gradle, MainApplication.ja according to npm documentation these are all fine.
Then I tried to run `react-native run-android` it's giving this error:[image]

Actual error occurring here:

`import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;`

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

`import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;`

with

`import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;`

in ContactsManager.js, ContactsProvider.js of node modules works for me.